# AngularJS date filter working on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox

I have a web page calling some PHP api and rendering results.
PHP queries a MySQL database and returns JSON objects that are deserialized and formatted using AngularJS directives and filters.

Problem rises as MySql dates are not directly supported by AngularJS date filter.
So I wrote this

```
angular.module(...)
  .filter('mysqlDateToISO', function() {
        return function(input) {
            input = new Date(input).toISOString();
            return input;
        };
    });
```

and HTML part looks like

```
<p>
   Pubblicato il 
   {{arg.pubblicato_il | mysqlDateToISO 
                       | date:"dd MMM yyyy 'alle ore' HH:mm:ss"}}
</p>
```

Chrome renders results properly:

> Pubblicato il 25 Mar 2015 alle ore 16:01:00

Firefox instead does not:

> Pubblicato il {{arg.pubblicato_il | mysqlDateToISO | date:"dd MMM yyyy
>   'alle ore' HH:mm:ss"}}

Firefox console shows this error

> RangeError: invalid date

The error is raised from `input = new Date(input).toISOString()`

How can I fix it?

Comment: In FF, is sth like : {{ arg.pubblicato_il }} correctly interpreted by AngularJS ? (<=> no more {{ ...  }}) ?

Comment: Is this a default `DATE` or a `DATETIME`? Can you give an example date formatted as it comes out of mysql? Or preferably a reproducible set of code?

Comment: @DylanWatt: it's a standard datetime, eg 2015-03-25 16:01:00

Comment: @RaphaëlBraud: `{{ arg.pubblicato_il }}` is processed correctly, but as a string and not as a datetime...

Comment: If you are seeing curly braces in on the page, that almost certainly means you had a JS error which prevented a proper angular compile. Do you have no errors in the console?

Comment: @DylanWatt: yes, I see `RangeError: invalid date` on Firefox console, but on Chrome it works properly... The error is raised from `input = new Date(input).toISOString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an alternative way to parse date string, such as Moment : http://momentjs.com/ by specifying the mysql date string format, then providing the output format.

Here is an example :

```
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").format("dd MMM YYYY [alle ore] HH:mm:ss")
```

Replace 20111031 with the mysql date serialization and YYYMMDD by the mysql date format.

Using moment will help to be more agnostic to browser Date implementation

More complete example :

```
angular.module(...)
  .filter('mysqlDateToISO', function() {
        return function(input) {
            var result = moment(input, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
                           .format("DD MMMM YYYY [alle ore] HH:mm:ss");
            return result;
        };
    });
```

Comment: I was already taking a look at MomentJs, but I don't understand where I'm supposed to convert the date: where should I use the sample instruction you gave me? In HTML as a custom directive or in controller code?